# How can I merge between two multidimensional array respected their keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-combine

Let's say I have following arrays:

```
Array
(
    [2001] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019
                            [cpd_points] => 23
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019 new
                            [cpd_points] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [2002] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2011
                            [cpd_points] => 28
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 20195 new
                            [cpd_points] => 12
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And the second one:

```
Array
(
    [2001] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2020
                            [cpd_points] => 27
                        )

                )

        )

    [2052] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2052
                            [cpd_points] => 258
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019445 new
                            [cpd_points] => 78
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And desired output is:

```
Array
(
    [2001] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019
                            [cpd_points] => 23
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019 new
                            [cpd_points] => 2
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2020
                            [cpd_points] => 27
                        )

                )

        )

    [2002] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2011
                            [cpd_points] => 28
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 20195 new
                            [cpd_points] => 12
                        )

                )

        )

    [2052] => Array
        (
            [event_detail] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2052
                            [cpd_points] => 258
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [event_name] => Advocacy CPD 2019445 new
                            [cpd_points] => 78
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The problem is I would like to merge these arrays on the same id[2001,2005,2002]. Desired output sorting should be the same as in the first array.

I have managed to merge these arrays with different way but failed:

How can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have tried a few php array function like array_merge / array_combine.Also I have tried in foreach loop. Can you share your best idea, please?

Comment: You can use my code.
$ar1 = array("2001" => array("event_detail" => array('1' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2019' , 'cpd_points' => '23'),'5' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2019 new' , 'cpd_points' => '2'))),"2002" => array("event_detail" => array('2' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2011' , 'cpd_points' => '28'),'4' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 20195 new' , 'cpd_points' => '12'))));

Comment: $ar2 = array("2001" => array("event_detail" => array('1' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2020' , 'cpd_points' => '27'))),"2052" => array("event_detail" => array('2' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2052' , 'cpd_points' => '258'),'4' => array('event_name' => 'Advocacy CPD 2019445 new' , 'cpd_points' => '78'))));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, just loop the second array and merge using the key to the first array:

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $val) {
    $array1[$key]['event_detail'] = array_merge($array1[$key]['event_detail'],
                                                $val['event_detail']);
}
```